# HTML/CSS aligning problems

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I have this section in my page and I want the arrows to be vertically aligned with the container, but I can't seem to be able to achieve this. Maybe it's a stupid question or I'm making a silly mistake, but I just started learning CSS and I'm not as good as I'd like to be. Thanks for your time!

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m53ED.png)

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  /* border: thin solid black; */
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

.slider-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.slider-slide svg {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 0%;
}

.slider-slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.slider-btns {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; /* Centra verticalmente los botones */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0; /* Reinicia la posición superior a 0 */
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slider a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: thin solid #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.slider a:hover {
  color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

```html
<section id="seccion12" class="section" data-scroll-spy>
        <h2>Responsive slider</h2>
        <br />
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="slider-slides">
            <div class="slider-slide active">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.theathletic.com/app/uploads/2023/10/04020934/GettyImages-1715814678-1536x1059.jpg"
                alt="Soccer"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="slider-slide">
              <h4>Diapositiva 2</h4>
              <p>
                Empezamos la semana adquiriendo conocimientos teóricos sobre
                JSON y las APIs, que veremos más adelante. Después de eso
                empezamos a estudiar el DOM, sobre el cual vimos los siguientes
                contenidos: Nodos, elementos y selectores Atributos y
                Data-Attributes Estilos y variables CSS Clases CSS Texto y HTML
                Traversing Creación de Elementos y Fragmentos Templates HTML
                Modificación de elementos
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="slider-slide">
              <img
                src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x1000/?stadium,night"
                alt="Stadium"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="slider-slide">
              <h4>Diapositiva 2</h4>
              <p>
                Empezamos la semana adquiriendo conocimientos teóricos sobre
                JSON y las APIs, que veremos más adelante. Después de eso
                empezamos a estudiar el DOM, sobre el cual vimos los siguientes
                contenidos: Nodos, elementos y selectores Atributos y
                Data-Attributes Estilos y variables CSS Clases CSS Texto y HTML
                Traversing Creación de Elementos y Fragmentos Templates HTML
                Modificación de elementos
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-btns">
            <a class="prev" href="#">
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="1rem"
                height="1rem"
                fill="currentColor"
                class="bi bi-arrow-left"
                viewBox="0 0 16 16"
              >
                <path
                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M15 8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H2.707l3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L2.707 8.5H14.5A.5.5 0 0 0 15 8z"
                />
              </svg>
            </a>
            <a class="next" href="#">
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="1rem"
                height="1rem"
                fill="currentColor"
                class="bi bi-arrow-right"
                viewBox="0 0 16 16"
              >
                <path
                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11.793l-3.147-3.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l4 4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-4 4a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L13.293 8.5H1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8z"
                />
              </svg>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

I tried changing the top, translate, display and position attributes, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Based on the CSS, I'm assuming that the height of the slider is 400px. Then if I compare it to the screenshot you provided, I'm also assuming the image is overflowing the content, where the image height is supposed to be 400px as well. That's the problem. If that so, my suggestion would be adding this into your CSS: `.slider-slide img { height:100%; object-fit:contain; width:100%; }`